# Spark Pipe function utilizes CPU only 50%

Tags: apache-spark

I have a legacy code in C++ that gets a file path on HDFS as input, runs and writes its output to local HDD.

Following is how I call it:

`val trainingRDD = pathsRdd.pipe(command = commandSeq, env = Map(), printPipeContext = _ => (),
      printRDDElement = (kV, printFn) => {
        val hdfsPath = kV._2
        printFn(hdfsPath)
      }, separateWorkingDir = false)`

I see CPU utilization around 50% on Ganglia. `spark.task.cpus` setting is equal to 1. So, each task gets 1 core. But my question is, when I call the binary with pipe, does that binary gets all cores available on the host just like any other executable or is it restricted to how many cores that pipe task has? So far, increasing `spark.task.cpus` to 2 didn't increase usage.

Comment: The C++ code is most likely not made to use multiple cores. Parallel computations are complicated, so people do not write parallel code if it is not needed. So you either need to make C++ code parallel or rewrite Spark code to run multiple C++ commands on multiple files.

Comment: It is indeed a multithread application.

Answer (score 0):

Spark it could read files parallel and also there have partition machilism in spark ,more partition = more parallel. if you want increase your CPU utilization you could configure your SparkContext to

```
  sc =  new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")
```

More details acess https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

Comment: In your code you don't even change parallelism. Even then, it has nothing to do with this.

Comment: Spark it running in parallel  you don't event use parallelism